# What is the minimum distance between medium voltage electrode and low v earthing electrode

Tags: grounding, system

And what is the best way for grounding the koisk which have medium section transformer and lv section. The required earthing system is TNS system that requires neutral and pe in the same electrode

Comment: What is a koisk?

Comment: "[kiosk](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kiosk)" implies a public-accessible structure.  Does this really have MV connected to a public-facing structure?

Comment: Yes consist of enclosure contain mv, trans and low voltage section all package in outdoor